# Visual Studio 2022. Can I build project with `dotnet build` by default instead of MSBuild?

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I want to develop, build and deploy app to my Raspberry Pi 3 from Visual Studio 2022 on my working PC with Windows 10.

Found, that I can build native Linux app with `dotnet.exe build -r linux-arm64 .\TestLinuxDeploy\TestLinuxDeploy.csproj --self-contained`

So, can I somehow modify single project behavior, to make default build (`Ctrl+Shift+B`) to run above command instead of building with MSBuild? Or redefine default MSBuild `Build` target, or something else...

My stack of googled info literally overflowed with tons of information about VS build process, but no clear one.

I expect, that I can define some properties in `.csproj` file, like `runtime`, `self-contained`, `single-package`, then hit big red "BUILD" button, and project will be built with `dotnet build <my parameters>`

Comment: offtopic: 2 days ago there was another answer. I accepted it as answer. But today it's gone and no signs of it in question history... wtf?

Comment: That answer might have been deleted for some reason. If it can help you to solve the problem, you can consider adding an answer and accepting it. See [can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild can be hosted within another application and this is what the `dotnet` tool is doing. It is the same build engine regardless of whether you use `msbuild` or `dotnet msbuild` (or `dotnet build` (which is essentially `dotnet msbuild /t:build`) or one of the other dotnet sub-commands that use the build engine).

There are two major implementations of .NET:

- ".Net Framework", the original implementation of .NET, is Windows only.
- ".Net" (previously known as .Net Core), is cross platform. (The naming is not at all confusing.)

The .NET SDK includes the `dotnet` tool and supports the ".Net" implementation but doesn't support the ".Net Framework" implementation. Visual Studio for Windows supports both implementations.

You can't change Visual Studio to use `dotnet msbuild` instead of `msbuild` but you don't need to.

You are correct to expect that there are properties.

Visual Studio uses separate publishing profile files (with a .pubxml extension).

The equivalent property for `-r` is `RuntimeIdentifier`, e.g.:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

See "[RuntimeIdentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#runtimeidentifier)".

`--self-contained` maps to a `SelfContained` property.

Both properties would be used in a publishing profile. See "[Deploy .NET Core apps with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs156)".